# How do i fix this dropdown button in my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

This is the beginning of the HTML code. Notice I put the div"dropdown" in the

element in order to add the drop down button into my fixed navigation bar I learned how to create before learning the dropdown button. Another issue with the added button is the hover on the other list items is not flush to the bottom of the nav bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Vasilios Lambos</title>
</head>

<body>
<header role="banner">
<div id="fixed">
<nav role="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Process</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Research</a>
            <a href="#">Exploration</a>
            <a href="#">Testing</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/vasilios-lambos-81220366">Contact</a>


</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>

<div class="jumbotron">
<img src="IMG_1677.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
<h1>Vaslios Lambos</h1>
<p>Industrial and Interaction Designer</p>
<p>Always staying hungry to learn new and inspiring ways to improve my creative process. I utilize design thinking, research methods, and ethonography to explore user experience and services. Core hard skills consist of user interface design, product rendering, and testing.</p>

</div>
<div class="pics">
<img src="VL-Logo.png" width="200" height="200"/>
</div>
<div class="info">
<div class="container">
<h3>Overview</h3>
<p> ### </p>

</div>

</div>
<div class="footer">
<h3>Soft & Hard skills</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Adobe Suite</li>
    <li>Axure RP</li>
    <li>HTML/CSS/Javascript</li>

</ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Below is the CSS code for how to style the dropdown and below that you can find the #fixed class for the nav bar.

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@font-face {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color: #FFF;
}
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.dropbtn{
background-color: #999;
color:white;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight:bold;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
z-index:-3;
}
.dropdown{
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a{
color:black;
padding:12px 16px;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover{
background-color:#3C6;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
background-color:#3C6;
}


#fixed ul{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
width:100%;
z-index:9999;
list-style-type:none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow:hidden;
background-color: #999;
}
nav li{
float:left;
}   
  nav li a{
  display:inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
 }

nav a:hover {
 background-color: #3C6;
 }

div.jumbotron {
margin-top:53px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:10px;
height:500px;
max-width:100%;
color:white;
text-align:center;
background-color:#000
} 
.jumbotron p{
width:500px;
margin-left:inherit;
margin-right:inherit;
}
.jumbotron img {
border-radius: 50%;
margin:inherit;
}

.pics{
/*float:right;*/
display:inline;
height:232px;
width:232px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
/*z-index:-1;*/
}
.pics img{
padding:15px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #eee;
width:200px;
height:200px;

}

div.info {
max-width:100%;
background-color: #000;
color:white;
padding:20px;
height:400px;
}
div.footer{
max-width:100%;
background-color:#000;
color:white;
height:400px;
padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your grammar.

Comment: Do you not have an answer for how to fix the above issue?

Comment: I found out i have overflow: hidden

Comment: Stupid question, but why do you have an XHTML doctype? The document isn't XHTML.